# Trouble understanding function pascal

Tags: function, pascal

Can someone explain what exactly the below function does? From my understanding it sorts numbers in an array from highest to lowest, is this correct?

```
function ArraySum(const data: array of Integer): Integer;
var
   i: Integer;
begin
   result := 0;
   for i := Low(data) to High(data) do
   begin
      result := result + data[ i ];
   end;
end;
```

Comment: It would help if you indicated the Pascal you are using. I assume Delphi or FreePascal. Am I right?

Comment: I would recommend taking a pencil and paper and run through a couple of simple examples with small arrays. You'll figure it out pretty quickly if you just step through it.

Answer (score 1):

The function calculates the sum of the data array and returns the sum.

- The loop indexes from the lowest (`Low(data)`) array index to the highest ( `High(data)`).
- `result` is the return value of the function. It is set to zero before the loop starts. Inside the loop, each data element is added to the result.

Comment: As written, the function may not actually return anything; in most Pascals of my experience, the return value is established by assigning the desired return to the function name (e.g., if the function name is ArraySum, the return value would be established within the function by the line `ArraySum := ...`).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, yes, returning the value with its function name works with all pascal compilers. Modern pascal compilers, like Delphi, FreePascal, prefer the use of the `result` variable though.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: In most Pascals I know (Delphi, FreePascal, Oxygene), you can use the Result pseudo-variable. In these Pascals, it is predefined for every function. It is a bit more convenient than assigning to the function name, since it can really be used like a variable, so you can indeed do `Result := Result + something;`, which is not possible for function names. The fact that `High()` and `Low()` are used too, plus open array parameters, indicates it is one of these languages.

Comment: I'm not convinced that 'prefer' is an appropriate word here; 'accommodate' or 'allow' might be better, and at least one 'old' Pascal I recall using provided `low()` and `high()`, and open arrays.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, yes, turbo pascal also had `Low()`,`High()` and open arrays. The reason to prefer the usage of the `result` variable is that it behaves as a real variable, you can use it in expressions—something you cannot do with the function name.

Comment: @LURD - I fail to see that as an advantage; assigning to the function name didn't immediately end the function, but it does provide a visual signal of what the return value is, vs. it being whatever happens to be stuffed into a not-entirely-random variable when the function happens to end.

Comment: @Jeff: The advantage is that you can do things like `Result := Result + 17;` like with any other variable. You can't do that with a function name. So you would have to *declare* your own result variable and assign it to the function name at the end.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - I fail to see this as an advantage; at best, it's a shortcut for lazy coders. There was a _reason_ that Wirth defined the language in such a way that all variables had to be declared before use, and using `Result` as 'modern' compilers appear to allow is a violation of that underlying philosophy.

Comment: (This has gone way off-topic, and really should be taken to chat - which for some reason is blocked by my employer's net-access policies. I'll concede that - depending on the particular compiler - the function as given will work; I wasn't actually disputing that in the first place. But an old purist like me will note the possible exception.)

Comment: The shortcut *is* an advantage. Perhaps not for you, but for most who are used to it. I immediately liked it, when it was introduced into the language, many many years ago. IOW, I do see it as an advantage. There is nothing wrong with making such things easier (for the lazy and non-lazy alike). Code is not better when it takes more effort to write. The pseudo-variable presents one less opportunity to make a mistake (e.g. inadvertent recursion), IMO.